# Is it possible to analyse the components of a composite score with a specific formula in a multivariate linear mixed model analysis?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

My goal is to analyze sex differences over time in a composite score that consists of 4 components (C1-C4) using a linear mixed model analysis. The secondary analysis includes sex differences over time in the different components. The regression coefficients of interest are gender, gender:time, and gender:component. The data is organized such that each patient's ID is recorded 20 times (4 times for each component at 5 different time points).

Assume that the relationship between the composite score and the overall score is as follows: `composite score = ((C1+C2)+(C3+C4)/2)/3`

I aim to develop a model that explores the variations in the 4 components over time and the main effect of gender and gender:time on the composite score, which is derived from the 4 components.

**Example data**

```
#Packages
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(tidyr)

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create a data frame with 11,000 observations
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:1000, each = 6),
                 Gender = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)), each = 6),
                 Time = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 1), 1000),
                 C1 = sample(0:100, 6000, replace = TRUE),
                 C2 = sample(0:100, 6000, replace = TRUE),
                 C3 = sample(0:100, 6000, replace = TRUE),
                 C4 = sample(0:100, 6000, replace = TRUE))

# Add 5 to the Response, Component1, Component2, Component3 and Component4 for females
df$C1[df$Gender=='Female'] <- df$C1[df$Gender=='Female'] + 5
df$C2[df$Gender=='Female'] <- df$C2[df$Gender=='Female'] + 5
df$C3[df$Gender=='Female'] <- df$C3[df$Gender=='Female'] + 5
df$C4[df$Gender=='Female'] <- df$C4[df$Gender=='Female'] + 5

# Reshape the data frame from wide to long format
df_long <- tidyr::gather(df, Component, Response, -c(ID, Gender, Time))

#Some pre-processing
df_long <- df_long[order(df_long$ID, df_long$Time, df_long$Component), ]
row.names(df_long) <- 1:nrow(df_long)
df_long$Gender <- as.factor(df_long$Gender)
df_long$ID <- as.factor(df_long$ID)
df_long$Component <- as.factor(df_long$Component)
```

**Structure of the data**

```
#Data-structure
head(df_long, n = 20)
str(df_long)

   ID Gender Time Component Response
1   1   Male    0        C1       95
2   1   Male    0        C2       96
3   1   Male    0        C3       81
4   1   Male    0        C4       27
5   1   Male    1        C1       17
6   1   Male    1        C2       61
7   1   Male    1        C3       29
8   1   Male    1        C4       75
9   1   Male    2        C1       44
10  1   Male    2        C2       99
11  1   Male    2        C3       91
12  1   Male    2        C4       94
13  1   Male    3        C1        5
14  1   Male    3        C2       18
15  1   Male    3        C3       36
16  1   Male    3        C4       57
17  1   Male    4        C1       71
18  1   Male    4        C2       89
19  1   Male    4        C3       64
20  1   Male    4        C4       34
```

**Analysis**

```
lmer_model = lmer(Response ~ 1 + Gender + Time + Component + Gender*Time + Gender*Component +  (1 | ID), data = df_long, REML = F)

    
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Response ~ 1 + Gender + Time + Component + Gender * Time + Gender *      Component + (1 | ID)
   Data: df_long

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 229768.5  229865.5 -114872.3  229744.5     23988 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7736 -0.8630  0.0105  0.8630  1.7492 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept)   0.743   0.862  
 Residual             840.448  28.990  
Number of obs: 24000, groups:  ID, 1000

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error         df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               54.3622     0.8627 17327.2083  63.010   < 2e-16 ***
GenderMale                -4.0358     1.0239 17327.2083  -3.942 0.0000813 ***
Time                       0.1066     0.2035 23000.0008   0.524     0.600    
ComponentC2                1.2672     0.9829 23000.0009   1.289     0.197    
ComponentC3                0.2046     0.9829 23000.0009   0.208     0.835    
ComponentC4                1.4241     0.9829 23000.0009   1.449     0.147    
GenderMale:Time           -0.2437     0.2415 23000.0007  -1.009     0.313    
GenderMale:ComponentC2    -0.5532     1.1665 23000.0009  -0.474     0.635    
GenderMale:ComponentC3    -0.5025     1.1665 23000.0009  -0.431     0.667    
GenderMale:ComponentC4    -0.5537     1.1665 23000.0009  -0.475     0.635    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) GndrMl Time   CmpnC2 CmpnC3 CmpnC4 GndM:T GM:CC2 GM:CC3
GenderMale  -0.843                                                        
Time        -0.590  0.497                                                 
ComponentC2 -0.570  0.480  0.000                                          
ComponentC3 -0.570  0.480  0.000  0.500                                   
ComponentC4 -0.570  0.480  0.000  0.500  0.500                            
GenderMl:Tm  0.497 -0.590 -0.843  0.000  0.000  0.000                     
GndrMl:CmC2  0.480 -0.570  0.000 -0.843 -0.421 -0.421  0.000              
GndrMl:CmC3  0.480 -0.570  0.000 -0.421 -0.843 -0.421  0.000  0.500       
GndrMl:CmC4  0.480 -0.570  0.000 -0.421 -0.421 -0.843  0.000  0.500  0.500
```

It is possible for me to examine sex differences over time for the individual components using this model. However, in this model, the main effect of sex reflects the mean of the 4 components and not the overall composite score. Would it be possible to analyze the effect of the 4 components on the model, whilst also having the main effect of sex reflect the overall composite score as opposed to the mean of the 4 components?